# Защита от дурака регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, мне нужно проверить на корректность входящую строку(сделать защиту от дурака). Которая следующего вида : два (и только два) числа и между ними оператор ( * / + - ) , числа могут быть отрицательными, может быть сколько угодно пробелов, не должно быть никаких других символов.
Хотелось бы, чтобы это считалось корректным:

```
 10+10
-10-10
-10*-10
и т.д.
```

А такие варианты отбраковывались:

```
-10**10
10*10 10
10-*10
10-/10
10-10 -
и т.д.
```

Я стал пробовать перебирать  в цикле и проверять IF-ами каждый символ. Но создалось впечатление , что сделать это будет не просто, будет очень много кода и наврятли удасться учесть все варианты ошибок. Вспомнил про регулярные выражения.

Помогите пожалуйста, можно ли решить это регулярным выражением. Если да , то как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так (если `-` всегда должен быть слитно с числом):

```
-?\d+\s*[+\-\*\/]\s*-?\d+
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогло! Немного некорректно реагировало на пробелы в некоторых местах, поэтому добавил их.
Получилось , что-то такое 
Pattern.compile("  *-? *\\d+\\s*[+\\-\\*\\/]\\s*-? *\\d+");

некорректно на сайте отображается выражение )

Comment: @fantastic: чтобы отображалось корректно, поставьте символ «`» с обеих сторон от кода.